# Как вывести массив Route в react-router-dom v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Всем привет! Раньше использовал react-router-dom v5 и все работало, но нужно было перейти на v6 и все сломалось.  В чем может быть причина? Если выводить Router не используя массив, тогда все работает.

//RouterComponent

```
<Routes>
    {allRoutes.map((route: IRoute) => {
              const path = Array.isArray(route.path)
                ? route.path.filter((item: string) => item === pathname && item)[0]
                : route.path;

              const authorization = (route: IRoute): boolean => {
                if (route.isAuth) return auth;
                if (route.isAdmin) return staff;
                if (route.protectRouteBasket) return basketIsNotEmpty;
                return false;
              };

              const protectedRoutes = route.isAdmin || route.isAuth || route.protectRouteBasket;
   
              return protectedRoutes ? (
                <Route
                  key={route.name}
                  element={
                    <ProtectedRoute authorization={authorization(route)}>
                      {<Route element={route.component} path={path} />}
                    </ProtectedRoute>
                  }
                />
              ) : (
                <Route
                  path={typeof route.path}
                  key={route.name}
                  element={route.component}
                />
              );
            })}
</Routes>
```

//config

```
export const allRoutes: IRoute[] = [
  { component: Main, path: "/", name: "main", isAdmin: false, isAuth: false },
  { component: AboutMe, path: "/aboutMe", name: "aboutMe", isAdmin: false, isAuth: false },
...
]
```

//ProtectedRoute

```
export const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<PropsProtectedRoute> = ({ authorization, children }) => {
  return authorization ? children : <Navigate to="/" />;
};
```

//Так работает

```
<Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Обновленный `<Route/>` в `react-router-dom` `v6` принимает компонент в таком виде

`<Route element={<Home/>} />`, а вы передаете `element={Home}`.

Вам привести компоненты в массиве к виду:

```
export const allRoutes: IRoute[] = [
  { component: <Main/>, path: "/", name: "main", isAdmin: false, isAuth: false },
  { component: <AboutMe/>, path: "/aboutMe", name: "aboutMe", isAdmin: false, isAuth: false },
...
]
```

Т.е. поменять `Main` на `<Main/>` и т.д.

Comment: Делал так и хардкодил, но компоненты  Route не рендрятся все равно. На просторах интернета не нашел решение проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. В общем, проблема была в путях и в иcпользовании параметра index.